# Get user input in loop without '[ENTER]'

Tags: python, loops, input

I have a loop reading from a com port...

```
import serial

def main():
    ser = serial.Serial(11, 4800, timeout = 1)
    ser.open()
    lines = []
    while True:
        line = ser.readline()
        print(line)
        lines.append(line)
        # check for **USER**  input without stopping
        # if input == ' ' or '\n' or what have you:
            # break
    ser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I perform the above pseudo code in the comments above? Is it even possible?

Comment: it is certainly impossible without stopping  for input. Where is the input supposed to come from?

Comment: I'm looking for `input()` without having to press enter. I read something about `signal` and `signal.alarm()` in a try: except, but I didn't like it.

Comment: Without getting really low level and monitoring the system events (such as keyboard events) you'll most certainly have a "stop and wait for return" input.

Comment: You're looking for a user input stream which I'm not sure exists within Python.  Also this is very bad programming practice.

Comment: Then what am I supposed to do in order to exit the loop without timing it or doing a `for i in range(100):...`?

Answer (score 0):

[ser.read()](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read) will return the next byte read.

Examples :

```
x = ser.read()          # read one byte
s = ser.read(10)        # read up to ten bytes (timeout)
line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
```

Comment: I meant user input... like `input('Please enter something and then press enter')` without having to press enter

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using [`curses.window.getch()`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch), but you'd have to write some initialization code around it, e.g. creating a window. Should not be overly hard, though.

Under MS Windows, you can use [msvcrt.getch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) to read the character; don't forget to check msvcrt.kbhit() if you don't want to block on reading.

Comment: I'm also using Python 3.4.1

Comment: I don't think curses.window exists in Python 3.

Comment: [Surely it does](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch). But if you're running MS Windows, it is not supported.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the case of Windows.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like it should work, but it stops when waiting for input and enter key doesn't work.